# Can I test an APK file with Dart Devtool, without having source code?

Tags: android, flutter-test, charles-proxy, flutter-debug, flutter-devtools

I am testing an .APK file made with Flutter with CharlesProxy to inspect the network traffic,
At this moment I have a problem with inspiring WebSockets network traffic **wss://**, Websockets are not available to inspect.

1- Is there any way to enable WebSockets to debug on flutter app, then I can inform developers to implement it, then I will be able to test WebSockets on Charles proxy?

2-Can I use Dart Devtool with **.APK** file without having access to source code?

Note:

- .APk made with Flutter.
- with .APK, which made with Kotlin everything works fine on Charles proxy.
- Charles setting is correct, I can see was:// for other apps.

your answer will help me, thanks.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this?